# How to convert the time type of 11:30:00 to 1130 in dolphindb database?

Tags: dolphindb

How to convert the time type of 11:30:00 to 1130 in dolphindb database?

I want to convert the time in a certain format. Take an example, I want to convert the time 11:30:00 to 1130, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use “hour” and “minuteOfHour” functions, for example:

```py
t=table(11:00:00 11:30:00 as tm)
select hour(tm)*100+minuteOfHour(tm) from t
```